# Is there a XSL-FO renderer which supports <fo:table table-layout="auto">?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, docbook

I'm using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert Markdown to Docbook, doing stuff to it then rendering the Docbook to XSL-FO using [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).  Unfortunately, Pandoc makes tables with table-layout="auto" and FOP only supports table-layout="fixed".

Is there a XSL-FO renderer which does support table-layout="auto"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commercial renders do. Try [Ecrion](http://www.ecrion.com) if you need speed.

Answer (score 6):

With FOP you get the features that someone decided they wanted bad enough to implement. I'd say that no one who's serious about publishing uses it in production. You're far better off with RenderX or Antenna House or [Arbortext](http://single-sourcing.com/products/arbortext/publishing.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=fop&utm_content=ati&utm_campaign=us).  (I've used them all over the last decade's worth of implementation projects.) It depends on your business requirements, how much you want to automate, and what your team's skills, time, and resources are like as well. It's not just a technology question.

Happy to discuss more offline.

Comment: "no one who's serious about publishing uses it in production" - ahem, we do!